# Mobile domain with 'm.' prefix does not displayed on address bar native Android browser

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, android-browser

in my application i did a redirection to mobile version:

```
location.href = 'http://m.' + host_name;
```

However i got a very strange behavior on native Android browser:

Enter http://mydomain.com --> browser redirect me to http://m.mydomain.com, but the URL in the address bar still display as "mydomain.com". When i refresh browser, it display correctly: "m.mydomain.com".

Enter directly "m.mydomain.com" work correctly.

P/s: this only happen when my script is minified. with Un-minified version, the browser display the URL correctly as "m.mydomain.com".

Any one experience this problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does the minifed code look like?

Comment: I can not put all the code to here.. but it's a normal minified file, with all functionality work quite well. just this problem drive me crazy!

Comment: may be this is related but couldn't found a reason yet.. .https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63481#makechanges